# dante-server not working with ipv6

Tags: proxy, ipv6, socks, dante

I always get

```
Error = 0x08 (Address type not supported)
```

when I try to open ipv6 addresses like ipv6.google.com via my dante-server.

How do I get danted to work with ipv6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the code, I'm afraid.  From [the current status page](http://www.inet.no/dante/status.html),

> The items below are all desired, but not currently being worked on.
>   See the survey for more information and how you can influence their
>   priority.
>
> ```
> IPv6 support/gateway.
> ```